# Unable to scrape data from dynamic page - Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working to **scrape** the reports from this site, I hit the home page, enter report date and hit submit, it's Ajax enabled and I am not getting how to get that report table . Any help will be really appreciated.

https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/176

I tried sending get and post using requests module, but failed as Session Time out or Report not Available.

EDIT:

Steps Taken so far:

```
URL = "theice.com/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/..."
with requests.Session() as sess:
   f = sess.get(URL,params = {'selectionForm':''}) # Got 'selectionForm' by analyzing GET requests to URL
   data = {'criteria.ReportDate':--, ** few more params i got from hitting submit}
   f = sess.post(URL,data=data)
   f.text # Session timeout / No Reports Found –
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I did .. sess.get(url) i mentioned above , then with that reponse I did a post ; say sess.post(url,data={})

Comment: I created a session , sess = requests.Session()

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already identified that the data you're looking to scrape is hidden behind some AJAX calls, you're already on your way to solving this problem.

At the moment, you're using python-requests for HTTP, but that is pretty much all it does. It does not handle executing JavaScript or any other items that involve scanning the content and executing code in another language runtime. For that, you'll need to use something like Mechanize or Selenium to load those websites, interact with the JavaScript, and then scrape the data you're looking for.

Comment: I get that, we had a word on tracker too, the issue is it opens in a new tab;

Comment: I get that, we had a word on tracker too, the issue is it opens in a new tab;https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3778

Comment: Given there's no such thing as "tabs" in requests, you'll have to add a lot more detail to your question above if you want any kind of help with this.

Comment: Step 1::

Goto https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/ConsolidatedDailyVolumeOIReport.shtml?selectionForm=

Step 2: Enter Date and hit Submit

** o/p opens in a new tab as URL  https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/ConsolidatedDailyVolumeOIReport.shtml

with form data such as ;reportdate, htmlbutton,sourcepage etc...

But when I simulate a post to above, it says session timeout...

Comment: It looks as if you didn't look closely enough into what your browser actually does. You probably want to investigate what a form's [action](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) attribute does.

Comment: Sure, I will improve, but is it possible to show an example here with same url I mentioned?

Comment: @ArunChandramouli I am not going to write new code for you. If you post exactly what you're using in your question, I will update it to correct it because then I can know exactly what you're doing and what you're doing wrong. I've given you a hint as to what I think you're doing wrong. If you investigate your page and the hint, I think you can solve this yourself.

Comment: Arun, you should edit your question with that code. It's unreadable and not understandable in that comment.

Comment: Say geturl = "https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/ConsolidatedDailyVolumeOIReport.shtml?selectionForm="

 sessions = requests.session()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
 }


getData = sessions.get(geturl)

source = html.fromstring(getData.content) # Here we get a form with frame and session id

Then I post to that form, but getting session time out error

Comment: <form id="selectForm" action="/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/ConsolidatedDailyVolumeOIReport.shtml;jsessionid=2D3E13A8A3AF3F1EAA41A0B034058526" 
target="targetFrame" class="form" method="post" onsubmit="if (typeof(doForm2Submit)=='function') {doForm2Submit(this); return false}; return true;">

Comment: When I access via selenium webdriver, I found that it is going to a new frame known as "targetFrame" and it's url will be 

https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/datawarehouse/ConsolidatedDailyVolumeOIReport.shtml?jsessionid=2D3E13A8A3AF3F1EAA41A0B034058526
jsessionid=2D3E13A8A3AF3F1EAA41A0B034058526 # is generated dynamically @ runtime

I did a post her and  got Session Expired.